# My table is not getting created in Sqlite (Toast for dataNotInserted) ....Code snippet below

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My table is not getting created in Sqlite (Toast for dataNotInserted).Code snippet below...

#### EXCEPTION

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: PETROL.DB (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO PETROL.DB(AMOUNT) VALUES (?)
```

#### Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ET1;
    Button B1;
    Button Bview;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);


        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        ET1 = findViewById(R.id.editText_amount);
        B1 = findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        Bview = findViewById(R.id.button_view);
        AddData();

    }


    public void AddData() {
        B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(Integer.parseInt(ET1.getText().toString()));
                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "DataInserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "DataNotInserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

#### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="PETROL.DB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="PETROL_TABLE";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="AMOUNT";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_2 + " INTEGER );");

        Log.d("data","ghgc");
    }

    public boolean insertData(int data)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contextValues=new ContentValues();
        contextValues.put("AMOUNT",data);
        Log.d("insertData",Integer.toString(data));
       long result= sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,contextValues);
       if(result==-1)
           return false;//to check if data is inserted
       else
           return true;
       //sqLiteDatabase.close();

    }
}
```

onUpgrade not mentioned since i'm still working on version 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is as per the message and is caused as your are passing the Database name **PETROL.DB** to the `insert` method instead of passing the table name. As per the method's signature :-

> `long insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)`
>
> Convenience method for inserting a row into the database. [SQLiteDatabase - insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

As such change :-

```
    long result= sqLiteDatabase.insert(DATABASE_NAME,null,contextValues);
```

to :-

```
    long result= sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contextValues);
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked....I was stuck with same code for like 3 days and your answer really helped :-)

Comment: @BudCode, that's good. Could you please tick the question as answered.